# Can a button contain a group in an Apple Watch app?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacebutton

I am trying to set an image inside a button (not background image) on Apple Watch. Is there a way you can put a group inside a button? I know we can do it the other way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in Interface Builder, in the Attributes inspector, you can change the Content type from Text to Group.